# same column names with join, how to select the desired one

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
select bands_albums.name from (select * from bands join albums on bands.id = albums.band_id) as bands_albums;
```

but I get the following error:

```
Query 1: ERROR:  column reference "name" is ambiguous
LINE 3: select bands_albums.name from (select * from bands join albu...
        ^
```

as both `bands` and `albums` tables have the same column `name`, how to fix this error if I want the `name` of bands? I tried `bands_albums.bands.name`, but didn
t work.

Comment: `SELECT *`  is a bad choice from the start, write only columns that you need so which is it bands.name or album.name?

Comment: See also https://dbfiddle.uk/ds__R-H7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write always all columns that you really want and never only `SELECT *`

```
select 
   bands_albums.name 
from (select bands.name 
       from bands join albums on bands.id = albums.band_id) as bands_albums;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alias tables and subqueries should do the job...

```
select 
    ba.name as bandalbumname
from (
     select 
           b.name 
     from bands b 
     join albums a on b.id = a.band_id
     ) as ba;
```

Also dont use * on select subquerys as said before.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to alias the tables. Also you shouldn't need to do a subquery in this case since you're just selecting a column from a join of all columns.

```
select b.name, a.name 
from bands b
join albums a on b.id = a.band_id;
```